# How to add title/key to an array of multiple objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following function, where its extracting some data from some files and return in an array

```
const extractTestCases = () => {
    const filesArray = []
    const filterTestSuite = files.filter(test => test.includes('.test.ts'))
    filterTestSuite.forEach(testsuite => {
        const feature = regexMatcher(testsuite, featureRegex, 1)
        const testSuites = fs.readFileSync(testsuite, { encoding: "utf8" });
        const testCases = regexMatcher(testSuites, TestRegex, 1)
        filesArray.push({ [feature]: testCases })
    })
    return filesArray;
}
```

which gives me an output like the following

```
[
  {
    featureCustom: [ 'somethig' ]
  },
  {
    featureInsp: [
      'bla bla',
      'foo foo'
    ]
  }
]
```

how to make it generate an output like the following

```
[
    {
        "features": [
            {
                "featureCustom": [ 'somethig'
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureInsp": ['bla bla','foo foo'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like?...

```js
const extractTestCases = () => {
    const filesArray = []
        filesArray.push({ [feature]: testCases })
    return [
      {
        features: filesArray
      }
    ];
}
```

Comment: cant retrun features: filesArray in an array syntax error

Comment: I did say 'like'. Don't just copy and paste the code, review it to know it will do what you need. I typed the variable name (filesArray) wrong (fileArray), which probably caused the syntax error.

Comment: @peter-seliger My point wasn't to write the code for them. My point was to show that they could adjust the return value to whatever data format they actually needed. The `filesArray` format doesn't change, only how they wrap and nest it.

Comment: it returns 
[
  {
    features: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
    ]
  }
]

Comment: okay fixed by using 
        Object.assign(filesArray, { [feature]: testCases })
instead of filesArray.push({ [feature]: testCases })